# android testing cannot find symbol method natural()

Tags: android, testing

I'm a newbie to android studio and hope to get some help from the community.I am testing alphabetical sorting. The problem is that android studio cannot resolve the method natural() even though I did the implementations and imports needed. I don't know what's the problem with this .

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: At your dependencies you have a mixture of `androidx` and `com.android.support` libraries. If I am not mistaken these are not designed to work together.

When you move to `androidx` you have to replace all the `com.android.support` pacages with the equivalent new replacements. This is a guide to work on this approach https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

If you are not planning to migrate then just remove all the `androix` and use the equivalent `com.android.support`.

Comment: Additionally, do not add screenshots with code its hard to read and with no value as the text is not searchable.